# iphone app GUI programming

Tags: iphone, user-interface

can you use an image (previously created with Photoshop) to design your app ?
I mean connecting the psd objects to functions in app etc.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of - you can create UIButtons, and set images as background.  Then you can wire actions in your code to the button presses.

Comment: ok, no all in 1 option so. I was wondering how was created an app such as awesome note.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

With the [Briefs framework](http://www.giveabrief.com/) you can take a series of images and make a functional iPhone application from them by setting what happens when you tap on particular areas of the screen.  While primarily intended for wireframes of applications, you could create a simple flashcard-style application from this.